# Why seaborn countplot do not sort my data frame?

Tags: pandas, types, bar-chart, seaborn

I made up a data frame as mydata (code is given below) to explain my problem easily.
The problem is seaborn countplot method do not sort my data and I do not know why?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

```py
#Example Data
mydata = pd.DataFrame()
mydata['column_id'] = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
mydata['column_value'] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
mydata['column_id']
mydata.info()

#Plotting
mycolor= sb.color_palette()[0] #first color of the list
sb.countplot(data = mydata, x='column_id', color=mycolor,
             order = [4,3,2,1]);
```

[The output is given here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZicI.png)

Comment: I run your code and it worked as expected

Comment: [This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96cGi.png) the output I get running your code. So it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
 you can use this solution
     sns.countplot(data = mydata, x='column_id', color=mycolor,order = mydata['column_id]);
     #and if you want sort by value_counts
     sns.countplot(data = mydata, x='column_id', color=mycolor,order = 
      mydata['column_id'].value_counts().index);
```